# How to proceed if sentence

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

I apologize that I'm not an ENGLISH native.

```
import datetime
from time import sleep
dt_now = datetime.datetime.now ()


while True:
    sleep(1)
    if dt_now.hour ==14 and dt_now.minute == 3:
        print("1")
        sleep(10)
        continue

    if dt_now.hour ==14 and dt_now.minute == 5:
        print("2")
        sleep(10)
        
    else:
        print("3")
```

I'd like to continue with this cord.

For example, when we are 14:3, it outputs "1."
Time has moved on at 14:4; originally, it put out "3".
but this cord outputs "1."

Please lend me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Variables don't update themselves automatically. You should keep updating `dt_now` by placing the assignment of the current time within the loop instead:

```
while True:
    dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    ...
```